# Adjust the distance between two x-axis values to be closer to each other

Tags: plotly

I have this chart and as you can see it I need to somehow make the distance between the two x-axis value to be closer in order to show the hidden point’s label. I only have two values for x-axis and I don’t need a huge chart for that. Is there any option that does what I am looking for?

In order to show the complete chart I need to use width of 700 which is too big for what I want it to be.

```
    var layout = {
      width: 230,
      height: 210,
      margin: {
        l: 10,
        r: 10,
        b: 60,
        t: 0,
        pad: 0
      },
      xaxis: {
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: true,
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Seconds',
          font: {
            size: 9
          }
        },
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: true,

      },
      font: {
        size: 10,
      },
      paper_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      plot_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you increase the `padding` property this would make that label visible, please let me know if `padding` solves your issue. Also padding will not increase the width of your plot.

```
var layout = {
      width: 230,
      height: 210,
      margin: {
        l: 10,
        r: 10,
        b: 60,
        t: 0,
        pad: 30
      },
      xaxis: {
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: true,
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Seconds',
          font: {
            size: 9
          }
        },
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: true,

      },
      font: {
        size: 10,
      },
      paper_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      plot_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    };
```